# unable to open plot .xvg files using grace

Tags: xmgrace

I have been using Grace to plot the graphs obtained from my GROMACS simulations for a long time. However, now when I try opening the .xvg files, I get an error:

> Raags-MBP:native tubulin energies Preetiwadhwa$ xmgrace potential.xvg 
>   Warning: locale not supported by Xlib, locale set to C Warning: Widget
>   must be a VendorShell. Warning: Fatal Error: 
>   _XmGetDefaultDisplay cannot be used prior to VendorS.Initialize, returns NULL
>
> Oops! Got SIGSYS
>
> Please use "Help/Comments" to report the bug. Abort trap: 6

Can you please help me with this? Than you in advance!

Comment: Does "xmgrace" without any other argument works? Are you using Mac OSX? It looks like an X issue... Have you tried using other software that uses X?

Comment: Yes! That's the interesting part. I have been working with many other software, none of which is having any problem. In fact, I was able to use Grace earlier, its just suddenly stopped working after I updated the command line tools and homebrew.

Comment: Could it be that your issue is connected to the one described [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-x11/issues/255)? I think you can check that by installing another software that uses motif (such as xpdf) and see whether it works or not. Apparently there is a workaround (see link above) which involves downgrading XQuartz and recompiling xmgrace (either from the sources or by using brew).